# How to use Data Driven Scenario for just the GET request, when the scenario first includes a POST request and then a GET request?

Tags: karate

My automated test includes two requests:

- first, a POST bulk request to modify the name of 3 "objects";
- second, a GET request to each object to confirm that the names have been modified. The idea here is to use the Data Driven Scenario feature, by using the "Examples:".

```
Scenario Outline: POST multiple objects names
    * header Authorization = $authHeader
    Given url $baseUrl
    And path "/objects/ids/bulk"
    And param list = "11,22,33"
    And request {"Label":"ChangedName11;ChangedName22;ChangedName33"}
    When method POST
    Then status 200
    * json response = response
    * match response['Successful Requests'] == '#[3]'
    * match each response['Successful Requests'] == {"Status": 200,"Resource ID": #number,"Message": "Resource updated!"}
    * match response['Failed Requests'] == '#[0]'

    * header Authorization = $authHeader
    Given url $baseUrl
    And path "/objects/ids/" + '<object>'
    When method GET
    Then status 200
    * match response['Label'] == '<label>'

    Examples:
      | object  | label
      | 11      | ChangedName1
      | 22      | ChangedName2
      | 33      | ChangedName3
```

The test didn't work the way I expected because it sends the POST request 3 times too, and what I wanted is just 1 POST request, and then 3 GET requests.

In case Karate doesn't allow that, I would like to hear someone else's opinion about the best approach for my test. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use the first response to drive the data-source, you can even do that:

```
Feature: using the results of an API call as a data-source

  @setup
  Scenario:
    * url 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
    * method get
    * def data = [{ id: 1, name: 'a' }, { id: 2, name: 'b' }]

  Scenario Outline: id: ${id} | name: ${name}
    * url `https://httpbin.org/anything/${id}`
    * param name = name
    * method get

    Examples:
      | karate.setup().data |
```

This is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76527245/143475

Otherwise, don't use a `Scenario Outline`, model your data as a JSON array and then you can do this:

```
Feature: mixing 2 http calls but the second one in a loop

  Scenario:
    * url 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
    * method post
    * table data
      | id | name  |
      | 1  | 'foo' |
      | 2  | 'bar' |
    * call read('@called') data

  @ignore @called
  Scenario:
    * url `https://httpbin.org/anything/${id}`
    * param name = name
    * method get
```

This is explained here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#data-driven-features