# Executing the API call multiple times with in the same feature file

Tags: karate

I am querying a database, extracting the data from the two tables, and storing the response as below.

- def id = 1 (This is a response of a first query and it will be single value always)
- def associatedRulesToID = [100,101,102,103,104,105] (second query might return multiple values)

Now, I need to call the API and pass both the values i.e. id and associatedRulesToID for which I followed the below appraoch.

```
* def fun =
"""
function(associatedRuleID)
{
karate.call('calling another feature and passing the id and associatedRuleID for executing the Get Call')
}
"""

* karate.forEach(associatedRulesToID ,fun)
```

My question is, is there any better approach to achieving the same result with in the same feature file and we can execute the API execution multiple times depending upon the second query response.

Comment: read this and try the example. I leave it as an exercise for you to choose which way you want to go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76618739/143475

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link, however I have already gone through this link and my scenario is bit different.

Comment: I don't think so. so I pass, and maybe someone else will be able to give a better answer