# In Karate, How to call delete api for each item that was retrieved from the get call

Tags: karate

First Get endpoint: `https://dev1.dev.abc.com/inventory-service/v1/menus`

Response:

```
{
    "menus": [
        {
            "id": "c8d96852-b91d-43df-905a-0d4b55aeb812",
            "name": "Automation_zrDkdWIV26Updated Menu",
            "providers": [
                {
                    "id": "W13WWKM5A0CJ6"
                }
            ],
            "createdTime": 1689577123895,
            "modifiedTime": 1689657044587
        },
        {
            "id": "2a4623eb-c576-4ce6-a7b8-2791e2dbc7bc",
            "name": "Automation_KpeCX8fI8EUpdated Menu",
            "providers": [],
            "createdTime": 1689679532847,
            "modifiedTime": 1689679893314
        },
        {
            "id": "86702976-2ecc-419c-9830-a25f5cd9d2c2",
            "name": "Automation_vRNmDvkCUiUpdated Menu",
            "providers": [
                {
                    "id": "P0TM42JX85RH4"
                }
            ],
            "createdTime": 1689679892833,
            "modifiedTime": 1689679893318
        }
    ]
}
```

Now i have to call a delete api as below with each `id` eg: "c8d96852-b91d-43df-905a-0d4b55aeb812" under the `menus` array one by one.
Endpoint: `https://dev1.dev.abc.com/inventory-service/v1/menus/id`.
The `id` specified in the endpoint for the aforementioned delete method will be retrieved from the get api response.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for java code or a cucumber script? In java it would be something like:

```
import com.intuit.karate.junit5.Karate;

class MenuDeleteTest {
  
  @Karate.Test
  Karate testDeleteMenu() {
    return Karate.run("menu-delete.feature")
      .tags("@deleteMenus")
      .scenarioOutline("Delete each menu item")
      .examples(ExamplesTable.create(readMenusFromResponse()))
      .relativeTo(getClass());
  }
  
  private static String readMenusFromResponse() {
    String response = ""; // replace with json
    String menuIds = "";
    JsonNode menus = new ObjectMapper().readTree(response).get("menus");
    for (JsonNode menu : menus) {
      menuIds += "|" + menu.get("id").asText() + "|\n";
    }
    return menuIds;
  }
}
```

Update, cucumber with javascript:

```
Feature: Delete menus

Background:
  * url 'https://dev1.dev.abc.com/inventory-service/v1'

Scenario: Delete each menu item
  Given def response = 
    """
    {
        "menus": [
            {
                "id": "123",
                "name": "Menu1",
                "providers": [
                    {
                        "id": "ABC"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    """
  * def menus = karate.jsonPath(response, '$.menus[*].id')

  * eval karate.forEach(menus, function(menuId){ karate.call('delete-menu.feature', { menuId: menuId }) })
```

Then the delete-menu.feature file like:

```
Feature: Delete Menu

Background:
  * url 'https://dev1.dev.abc.com/inventory-service/v1'

Scenario: Delete a menu
  Given path 'menus', '<menuId>'
  When method DELETE
  Then status 200
```

Comment: Looking for a cucumber script, where we can use javascript function in between aswell

Comment: ok I updated answer, I think that's right, not 100% sure...

Comment: Thanks Andrew, it worked, just change karate.call instead of karate.callSingle. Its a big relief. thanks man

Comment: @PulkitAgrawal have a look at this test (last part) for an alternative approach: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-todo/blob/main/src/test/java/app/api/simple/restful-booker.feature - also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76618739/143475