Karate BDD - Fetch data from database in loop
I have a scenario as :
Step 1 : Data fetched from table1
Step 2 : If Data is NOT present in table2
Step 3 : This Data is to be checked for status using an API.
If the status is true, then the Data can be used for further execution,
If the status is false, then the process is to be restarted to Step 1 for the same process
Is there a way in karate BDD that I can do that?

I suggest you frame a better question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - but anyway, the answer is yes - refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76618739/143475 - and by the way I absolutely do not recommend these kinds of "clever" tests with conditional logic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475
